# vSphere Build Version via API

Tags: rest, api, vsphere, pyvmomi, rbvmomi

Is there a way do get the vsphere build versing using any API/SDK/REST?

I know it's possible using powershell on vcenter for that, but it'd be great if there was another option.

Like described here: https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2017/08/powercli-script-to-help-correlate-vcenter-esxi-vsan-buildversions-wo-manual-vmware-kb-lookup.html

Comment: What version/s of vSphere are you looking to do this against?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to using the [VMware vSphere API Python Bindings](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi), as you can just simulate going through the Managed Object Browser.

```
Parent Managed Object ID: ServiceInstance
Property Path: content.about
```

And then there is a `build` string which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do this, my need is having as much information about vsphere as possible, so get datacenter, cluster and host details is mantaroy.

For that I used the official ruby api, rbvmomi, but I believe it's exactly the same thing for python one and golang.

It's needed to interact through host folder under root/children object, which is not that clear on wmware api docs, to get it easier follow a piece of code:

```ruby
vim = RbVmomi::VIM.connect host: host, user: 'user', password: 'pass', insecure: true, debug: false
vim.root.children.each do |root_child|
    root_child.hostFolder.children.each do |child|
        child.host.each do |host|
            prod = host.config.product
            puts host.name,                             
               prod.apiType,                     
               prod.apiVersion,                 
               prod.build,                           
               prod.fullName,                  
               prod.instanceUuid,             
               prod.licenseProductName, 
               prod.localeBuild,              
               prod.localeVersion,         
               prod.name,                           
               prod.osType,                      
               prod.productLineId,         
               prod.vendor,                       
               prod.version
        end
    end
end
```